# How do i use an interface to interact between two classes

Tags: java, oop, interface, implementation

Say there are two classes A , B and class B has a button object and when i click the button class B should inform class A. I should do this by creating an interface between the classes and implementing it. how do i do this ? thanks.

what i have done is this

```
    interface Listener{
     void clicked();
    }

    class A implements Listener{
     void clicked(){
     // click informed to A
     }
    }

    class B {
     Button b = new Button();
     Listener l = new A()

     // say this method gets called by the button when it is pressed
     void buttonIsClicked(){
      l.clicked();
     }

    }
```

i have done it like this but my guide says that i am creating a new "A" and so its like i am informing to a new guy that the button is clicked. i don't get how do i inform "A" without creating an object of "A".

pls help

Comment: you can tell us what you have tried

Comment: SO is not the place for basic programming tutorials.

Comment: @sidgate i have updated what i tried pls check thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying Observer pattern to your code. Class B should hold (injected) list of Listeners and shouldn't know anything about concrete listeners implementations. This will allow you to decouple *Subject* (Class B) from *Observers*.

Answer (score -3):

Do you absolutly have to use interface for this? Another way of communicating between classes is through [Local Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). To checkout how to handle communication using this checkout [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager).

Comment: 1) This question is far too broad (or very unclear) and as such can't and shouldn't be answered. 2) OP is asking a general design question. A specific Android mechanism is itself not a good answer.

Comment: Especially because nothing in the question says Android. It could easily be a Swing program or something else entirely.